# Extract Regular expressions match found

Tags: python

So I'm trying to extract the match output that was found using Regular Expressions.

Code:

```
import re

def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

match = findWholeWord('seek')('seek the great glory')
print(match)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='seek'>
```

But I want text like, "MATCH FOUND: seek".

How can I do this? My knowledge of Python is not that much.

Comment: As it says, if you print `match.match`, it will show you "seek".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `.group(1)` of your match, then build up a string with the text you'd like to output

```
>>> print('MATCH FOUND: {}'.format(match.group(1)))
MATCH FOUND: seek
```

When you use capture groups in your regex you can use [`.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) to index which group you are interested in.

Then you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert this value into a string where the `{}` braces are placeholder(s).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Could you explain what the above code does so I can learn? Thanks.

Comment: @Cassano I've updated my answer with a couple of links to the docs with more details about each component used in this answer. Let me know if anything specifically is unclear.